# Axis2 Servlet : Etat HTTP 500 - "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, apache-axis

I'm trying to learn how to make a Web Service with Axis2. So, I saw this tutorial and I did like it. But when I start my tomcat server, I have this error :
[Server Tomcat Error][1]

Then, when I try to run my project on the server I get this error:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception
```

type Rapport d''exception

```
message "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



cause mère 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



cause mère 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:70)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



cause mère 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:70)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



cause mère 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:70)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? I've had one week searchin for a solution and I didn't fint any.

Comment: Looks like a configuration problem in your logging (NPE in `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor`)

Comment: How can I fix this?